# How to call a function by pointer by iterator?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have declared a global type:

```
typedef void ( MyClass::*FunctionPtr ) ( std::string );
```

then I need to use it in my function:

```
void MyClass::testFunc() {
}
void MyClass::myFunction() {

    std::map < std::string, FunctionPtr > ptrsMap;
    ptrsMap[ "first" ] = &MyClass::testFunc;

    std::map < std::string, FunctionPtr >::iterator it;
    it = ptrsMap.begin();

    ( *it->second ) ( "param" );    // How to call this function?

}
```

Problem is to call function by pointer using iterator of std::map. How to call that function?

I suppose all will work fine if I declare "it" as a global variable and call smth like that:

```
( this->*it->second ) ( "param" );
```

but I need to call that function using a local variable.

Comment: Member function pointer being the important thing

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit but how can I call it? :)

Comment: `it` doesn't need to be a global variable for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member function needs to be associated with an instance.

```
    MyClass k;
    (k.*it->second)("param");
```

or you can use the current object

```
(*this.*it->second)("param");
```

Also your `testFunc` needs to take a string parameter.

Comment: But how can I create an object if I need to call that function inside that object? :)

Answer (score 2):

`FunctionPtr` is a member function pointer, so it needs to be called on an object.
Using the pointer-to-member binding operator `.*`:

```
MyClass object;
...
(object.*it->second)("param")
```

Comment: Wait but I can't create an object because I've already stays in it

Comment: Or to call the object itself:
`(this->*it->second)("param")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a member function needs an object to be applied on.

One  way to do this is with function objects:

```
auto f = std::bind(it->second, this, std::placeholders::_1);  // first bind is for object
f (std::string("param"));    // How to call this function?
```

By the way, in your code sample, you should correct the signature of the test function to:

```
void MyClass::testFunc(std::string)  //  FunctionPtr requires a string argument
```